# Cheapest HV AC detector

Tags: ac, voltage-detector

I need to detect AC voltage with MCU for ensure relay health condition, the cheapest and smallest solution are most welcome.
I have no hard time restrictions or noise canceling\debounce requirements (will processed inside MCU).

Most of cheapest optocouplers (OC) has adequate `CTR` only with `If >= 1mA`. But with `VAC 230V`, the dropping resistor (`Rdr`) must have decent power dissipation raiting, size and price.

To use SMD or cheapest THT resistors, in worst case `Vac == 270V`, i must have `Prdr < 0.2W`. It means, what `Rdr` must be not less `360k` (or `510k` for long life safety).
So in another wrost case `Vac == 185`, i will have `If ~= 0.3mA` with pretty low `CTR`.
For example, for TCMT110x what i used in project it would be near 0.2x.

Ok, that looks pretty clear, i just need to use:

1. Double diode optocoupler (otherwise the `OC` will breaked by reversed 230VAC voltage).
2. Amplifting transistor on the output.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fL0ZOZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Does my thoughts has mistakes?
Does i not consider some effects, what i must consider?

Comment: Note: when your question title says HV most of us will be expecting > 1 kV. "Mains" would be a better description. There are dozens of zero-cross detection circuits on this site which would do the job for you. A capacitive dropper will solve most of the power dissipation problem since you don't care about any phase shift that it would introduce.

Comment: You might want to consider using 2 (or 3) resistors in series. A single failure mode can make your circuit dangerous.

Comment: Series of resistors are not an option because lack of place. Capacitive dropper too because same problem and also BOM cost. I am doesn't need zero-crossing detection, only voltage presence without any time restrictions. What you mean under dangerous? If Rdr are going to break, device just detects relay fault and disable the circuit.

Comment: If you can debounce in software why can't you use a single LED optocoupler? How quickly must you detect a loss of ac?

Comment: Do you have any safety requirements for this? What happens if Rdr fails short instead of open? You are using resistors rated for high voltage, aren't you?

Comment: As i understand, reverse voltage will break it. Cheap OC has Vrev-max in units of volts. Is im wrong?

Comment: Practically i have no time limits, one second would be fine. It is just relay open\close self check circuit. 

If Rdr somehow fails short - device will detect surge and goes fault? For 510k i want to use generic THT as it has 250\500 nominal\overload voltages. 

I have no any safety requirements, but be happy to use it.

Comment: If you can use a single LED optocoupler you can add a regular diode in parallel to it to limit the reverse voltage. BOM cost vs. space, I suppose. Keep in mind that an ac rms voltage of 270 V implies a peak voltage of over 380 V. I wouldn't use a resistor specified with a nominal voltage of 250 V. If it fails short, how do you detect this and shut off power before the fire starts?

Comment: Ah thats a mistake. Im tooked resistors 250V limit as 250VAC. Sure, i change it.

Comment: On failing short, the surge must occured, the surge detection circuit must get it. Is im wrong?

Anyway series of resistors and cap divider has same problem, isnt it?

Comment: "*Series of resistors are not an option because lack of place.*" Wrong approach. Series resistors are a requirement so that peak voltage is spread across multiple devices to ensure that breakdown or breakover does not occur and subsequent fire. *"I am doesn't need zero-crossing detection, ...*" I know. That's why I said that "they will do the job [mains detection] for you".

Comment: Implied what resistor has a right voltage raiting. Or it doesnt matter? As i know the line sometimes conduct HV impulses and thats the real reason?

Comment: The resistor will have a voltage drop across it. Its insulation strength needs to be adequate to deal with that, both across the resistor terminals, and the resistor to its mounting, same as if it were a wire. More here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/118489/voltage-rating-vs-power-rating-of-a-resistor

Answer (score 2):

Anything that requires you to attach to the line is a hazard, even with an optocoupler. Dropping circuits are the worst. They're totally unsafe, for a number of reasons:

- they bring line close to low voltage
- they dissipate power
- they have to deal with *creepage*
- they don't protect from transients

Consider instead using a capacitive sensor, something like those cheap testers that pick up live voltage. Then there's complete galvanic isolation, certainly better than what you will have with the optocoupler. This requires no direct attachment to the line, only proximity to it, so all the insulation distance and creepage issues go away. It saves the cost of the optocoupler, and your board can be smaller owing to not needing the opto or the stand-off distance. So this meets your 'cheapest' requirement, by far.

This kind of a sensor is a popular and cheap hobby project. Example here: https://www.electronicshub.org/non-contact-voltage-tester/

Comment: Can you explain the point of hazard in dropping circuits with optocoupler?

Comment: Any contact you make with the line is a hazard, and must provide adequate stand-off distance between the line voltage and low voltage, including allowing for creepage. Resistors must be large enough to deal with the voltage differential across them, and be sized for adequate power (other commenters noted this.)

Comment: Dropping circuits usually also use a capacitor by the way. Nevertheless I still don't recommend your approach.